# add table data javascript using form

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a kind of gradebook that lets me add basic student information and adds it to a table. My issue is: I cannot get the submitted information to show up on the table.

https://jsfiddle.net/20gs4xh2/

```
function submit(){
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value
var finalGrade = document.getElementById('finalGrade').value
var submit = new student(firstName, lastName, finalGrade);
studentdata.addstudenttotable(submit);
resetEntries();
updateGradebook();
}
function updateGradebook(){
document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML = '';

studentdata.data.forEach(function(elm){
    var row = document.createElement('tr')
    row.innerHTML = "<td>" + elm.firstName + "</td><td>" + elm.lastName + "</td><td>" + elm.finalGrade +"% </td>"
    document.getElementById('tbody').appendChild(row);
})
```

Comment: are you allow to use jquery?

Comment: yes I can use jquery.

Comment: Your submit() function is not getting called because `submit()` on the button initiates a form submit. You need to change the name of that function first. And then I see you are doing a `new student` but there is no `student` prototype defined. Nor have you initialised `studentdata` but you are using it. There are lot of problems with your code.

Comment: Where's your code for `student` and `studentdata`?

Comment: i agreed with the comments above regarding student data structure.  See the response below for how to add it to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Jquery.  Keep in mind, the default action for type button is submit a post or get.  So, if you don't want to do that, you have to do event.stopProgagation().  Not using jquery, I believe you can do `onclick="function(); return false"`.  https://jsfiddle.net/50tskqtu/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(event) { 
        event.stopPropagation(); //stop the default behavior of type button
        var row = $('<tr></tr>')
      row.append('<td>'+$('#firstName').val()+'</td>')
      row.append('<td>'+$('#lastName').val()+'</td>')
      row.append('<td>'+$('#finalGrade').val()+'</td>')
        $('#tbody').append(row)
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your table an Id of 'customer_data'

```
function submit(){ 
                var table = document.getElementById('customer_data');
                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                var td1 = document.createElement('td');
                var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                var td3 = document.createElement('td');

                td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
                td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
                td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('finalGrade').value;

                row.appendChild(td1);
                row.appendChild(td2);
                row.appendChild(td3);

                table.children[0].insertBefore(row, table.children[0].childNodes[1]);

                resetEntries();
          }
```